# Is there a repair only CD image(ISO)?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, live-cd, boot-repair

so basically, is there any way of creating live CD that has no apps other than ones necessary for repairing existing Ubuntu installation and fits in 700mb CD?

particularly Lubuntu 18.04 amd64 version since this is the one I have installed.

Answer (score 3):

There are several linux live systems for repair or rescue purposes. See for example this link,

[Top 5 Linux System Rescue CDs](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/top-5-linux-system-rescue-cds)

I have tried

- The Ultimate Boot CD (current version 5.3.8 fits on a standard CD disk)
- System Rescue CD (current version 6.0.2 too big for standard CD disk)

but I think the other alternatives are also worth trying.

- Rescatux (current version 0.51b3 fits on a standard CD disk)
- Tiny Rescue Kit (current version TRK 3.4 build 372 fits on a standard CD disk; from 2011, could fit old computers, might fail to repair new versions of file systems or bootloaders)

---

You can also use a small enough 'regular' linux distro for this purpose, depending on whether the tool that you need is available, for example

- Tiny Core
- Puppy linux (there are several versions and flavours).

---

Knoppix is a powerful alternative for a rescue and all-round live system, if you need not squeeze the live system into a CD.

- There are current Knoppix DVD size iso files to be burned to DVD disks or cloned to USB pendrives (now at version 8.2 dated 2018-05-10)
- There are also Knoppix CDs, but the newest version, that I can find, is getting old (version 7.2 dated 2013-06-16)

But if you need not squeeze the live system into a CD, please consider using your **Ubuntu** iso file (burned to a DVD disk or cloned to a USB pendrive) for repair or rescue of the installed system.

Answer (score 1):

For Lubuntu there is an "Alternate" installer/live ISO which should fit on a CD-ROM. This is also useful for running on a system with 1024 MB or less RAM.

See here for download links:

[Lubuntu 18.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/bionic/release/)

Also see [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Yeah, I just checked and it's over 700mb, like 714mb and it won't fit on CD sadly. My old PC only have a CD drive not DVD and all USB ports are fed up with soft raid-0 boot drives so...

Comment: For $14, upgrade your CD drive to a DVD drive. Problem solved.

Comment: Most burning software supports over burn, which can write 800-900MB of data to a CD. And there's no unit named "mb"